# Calling assertArrayEquals in junit test executed using ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, tdd

Im using ant to build my project, and im using junit for writing tests. I am facing a strange problem. Consider the code below

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class Test extends TestCase {

    public Test(String name) {
       super(name);
    }

    public testA() {
          //..Code 

          Assert.arrayEquals(expected,actual) //This does not work
          org.junit.Assert.arrayEquals(expected,actual) //This works !

    }
}
```

**Why do i need to append org.junit and not be able to use Assert class directly?**. I have setup junit in my build.xml as follows:

```
<property name="lib" value="./lib" />
<property name="classes" value="./build/classes" />
<property name="test.class.name" value="Test"/>


<path id="test.classpath">
      <pathelement location="${classes}" />
      <pathelement location="./lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
      <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
</path>


<target name="test" depends="compile">
        <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
            <test name="${test.class.name}" />
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
          </junit> 
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import junit.framework.*;
```

to

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

I'm not exactly sure what the `junit.framework` package is for but the import static trick is the common solution and is documented on [Assert's Javadoc page](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that is still not working. i still get symbol not found error if i call Assert.assertArrayEquals.

Comment: Hmm, odd, with the above code you don't even need the Assert class prefix, ie simply assertArrayEquals should work.